# Change default key to escape pointer lock on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am trying to build a web page where I have an interactive game running on the page. I need the user to be pointer locked while playing and want to use the escape button to pause the game and show menu. But Escape also by default exits pointer lock. This can get annoying for the user so I want to change the default key to exit pointer lock to some other key and show it in the message that shows up on top when pointer lock is engaged. Is this possible and if so how?

I have tried event listeners for keys but when pointer lock is on, Escape event is not fired at all, so I cannot do prevent default. I would be willing to look into either website code or if not possible there, I can also develop and extension. But so far I have not been able to change this functionality.

I understand this is part of chromes functionality to prevent abuse by scam sites and ads, but if I were to clearly show the user the replaced key, I think this should be allowed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [KeyboardLock](https://github.com/WICG/keyboard-lock/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for your answer. The [KeyboardLock](https://github.com/WICG/keyboard-lock/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) API works. It is however limited to Chrome only as of now.